# Как сделать, чтобы при отправке пустой формы, поля формы, которые не были заполнены становились красными?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вполне обычная форма, со всеми обязательными полями, как изменить атрибут рекваред так, чтобы при отправке не высвечивалось сообщение от бразуера, а поля меняли бордер? Если вообще возможно редактировать атрибут, если нет, то подскажите альтернативу, пожалуйста.

```
<form action="">
  <div class="form-inner">
    <p><input placeholder="Name" name="name" required></p>
    <p><input placeholder="City" name="city" required></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Email" name="email" required></p> 
    <p><input placeholder="Subject" name="subject" required></p>
    <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="mesage" required></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: при отправке формы проверять в js заполненность, выставлять css-классы для ошибочных

Comment: Можно чуть более подробно? Я мягко говоря "немного" слаба в этом, но передо мной стоит конкретная задача, на которую я довольно долго искала ответ, но из этого мало что получилось, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно вот так:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let form = document.querySelector('.form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    let controls = this.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
    let isValid = true;
    controls.forEach(control => {
      control.classList.remove('invalid-control');
      if (control.classList.contains('required') && !control.value) {
        control.classList.add('invalid-control');
        isValid = false;
      }
    });
    
    if (!isValid) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.invalid-control {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.form-control {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-inner">
    <p><input placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control required"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="City" name="city" class="form-control required"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control required"></p> 
    <p><input placeholder="Subject" name="subject" class="form-control required"></p>
    <p>
      <textarea placeholder="Message" name="mesage" class="form-control required"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант (+)

Comment: Такая же проблема, что и с кодом ниже, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Diretide Думаю, если Вы покажите код, будет проще понять в чем проблема

Comment: К сожалению, код превышает лимит по символам в комментариях, а скрином я вставить это тоже не могу, есть ещё варианты, как я могу показать код?

Comment: @Diretide https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: https://codepen.io/diretide/pen/poNYqBE

Comment: @Diretide https://codepen.io/bamberg/pen/rNWRPNG
У Вас не установлен border, поэтому цвет не менялся. Если заполнить все required поля, то форма отправляется

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```js
document.querySelector('#form [type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let form = e.target.closest('form');
  [...form.querySelectorAll('[required]')].forEach(function(e){
    if(!e.value.length > 0) {
      e.removeAttribute('required');
      e.classList.add('--required');
    }
  });
  if(form.querySelectorAll('.--required').length > 0)
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('--required') 
  && e.target.value.length > 0) {
    e.target.classList.remove('--required');
    e.target.setAttribute('required', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.--required {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
  <div class="form-inner">
    <p><input placeholder="Name" name="name" required></p>
    <p><input placeholder="City" name="city" required></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Email" name="email" required></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Subject" name="subject" required></p>
    <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="mesage" required></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Вариант мне нравится, но кнопка вообще не реагирует, т.е. она не отправляет форму, но и ошибку тоже не показывает. Из плюсов хотя бы не выплывает "бесячее сообщение браузера", возможно я что-то делаю не так

Comment: Даже не могу предположить с чем проблема. Ваш код сильно отличается от того что в примере?

Comment: Нет, разве что в форме на 3 поля больше, но я не думаю, что это является прям сильным отличием.

Comment: Возможно ли, что я просто не туда вставляю скрипт? Есть правил где он конкретно должен находиться, чтобы он срабатывал при конкретном действие?

Comment: Да, если скрипт располагается перед самой формой, то в момент работы скрипта он не видит форму. Посмотрите что пишет консоль.